# When do you need to use default="{'sobjectType': 'ObjectName'} for an aura:attribute?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, aura, aura-attribute

I'm getting the below error- when I type into a `lightning:input` whose `value` attribute is bound to a field on the custom object- when I don't use the `default` attribute. Is this because the `default` attribute is required for custom objects?

### This works

```
<aura:attribute name="customObject" type="CustomObject__c"
                default="{'sobjectType': 'CustomObject__c'}"/>

<lightning:input  label="First Name" required="true"
                  value="{!v.customObject.FirstName__c}"/>
```

### This errors out

```
<aura:attribute name="customObject" type="CustomObject__c"/>

<lightning:input  label="First Name" required="true"
                  value="{!v.customObject.FirstName__c}"/>
```

[image: error]

### Research

I don't see anywhere in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_object_salesforce.htm) mentioning that this is required. Rather it seems it is intended for default values, see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_attribute.htm).

Furthermore [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_attributes_expressions) Trail Head example seems to clearly not need it for a custom object.

[image: trail head example]

Comment: How are you using `customObject`? Are you creating an instance in the JS or you are receiving value after server call?

Comment: Creating an instance in JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments:

> Creating an instance in JS

Defaulting the attribute makes sure that you have an **instance** created for the object. If you don't have it defaulted, and if you attempt to utilize it in JS or the component, you will get a `null` instance. And thus, if you attempt to utilize a `null` instance further, you will get an error.

---

So, if you want to utilize an `SObject` instance in your component or JS, then you have to use default the `sobjectType` during declaration to create an instance of the object, and then utilize it in your component or JS to populate other fields or use for further operations.

```
<aura:attribute name="customObject" type="CustomObject__c"
                default="{'sobjectType': 'CustomObject__c'}"/>
```

OR

If you don't provide default, you will need to make sure you construct the object in the JS on initialization and provide the `sobjectType` attribute and utilize it accordingly.

```
var c = {'sobjectType' : 'CustomObject__c', 'Field1' : field1Value};
```

Comment: Thank you this makes perfect sense. Although from the TrailHead it seems that you can utilize it without creating an instance. See image above for Expense__c

Comment: Note this from trailhead -- *Here’s a **stripped down** look at the `expenseItem` component, which we’ll fill in later.* So that's only for reference as how you can declare an attribute. It does not really uses it in any JS context to populate or instantiate the attribute.

Comment: I see now that I didn't really understand your question above, my apologies. I'm not creating an instance in the JS, nor am I receiving a value after server call. The error is occurring well before that, when I start typing into the input whose value attribute is bound to a field on the custom object (the error is occurring before the code hits any JS controller or helper code). I updated my question to reflect this above.

Comment: @shmuels The answer still remains the same. You need to default to be able to create an instance before you could actually use it. I updated a bit of the verbiage.

Comment: Thank you. I wish this was in the docs; it's pretty crucial that you must instantiate the attribute before using it.

Comment: In my experience you don't need to specify 'sobjectType' in the default, just write default="{}" so that an object is instantiated.  Is there any documentation saying that we should set the sobjectType parameter?  I can't find any

Comment: @ministe2003 I haven't or didn't really try it out that way but I have seen this approach around [docs/trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_dev_lc_basics/lex_dev_lc_basics_forms) examples.

Answer (score 1):

The new LWC components typically check their configuration in an afterRender or connectedCallback function, and can throw errors if there's missing data. The two general solutions are to either hide the components by default (e.g. `<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.attr))}">`), or provide a default value. Not all components follow this rule though, so it's not in the documentation only because it is not a universal truth; many LWC components are more lenient and will allow you to set the data later.

Comment: In this specific scenario, it's a `null` vs. an empty instance which possibly could cause issue if you attempt to access `null` instance elsewhere in the JS. Defaulting ensures you are dealing with an empty instance.

Comment: I'm not using LWC, does Aura work the same way? I should've mentioned that I'm using lightning:input; is this one of the components which work this way? I think it should probably still be in the docs where applicable.

Comment: @shmuels LWC is the underlying component for many standard components, even in Aura. I do agree it would be nice to have a list of components and attributes that can throw exceptions.